# How to build a query that sums balance from transactions with switching sender and recipients

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm setting up a script that calculates the balance of a user by only using a transaction table and without the luxury of a balance table. Now i want to try to make one query that does this, is this possible and if so, how do i do this?

This is for an internal application that uses an already existing code base/database. For now I've done it by just using php.

```
$outgoing = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Transaction::class)->findBy([
    'sender' => $user,
    'contract' => $contract
]);

$incoming = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Transaction::class)->findBy([
    'recipient' => $user,
    'contract' => $contract
]);

$history = $outgoing + $incoming;

foreach ($history as $index => $transaction) {
    if ($transaction->getTokens() > 0) {
        continue;
    }

    unset($history[$index]);
}

usort($history, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a->getCreatedOn() === $b->getCreatedOn()) {
        return 0;
    }

    return $a->getCreatedOn() > $b->getCreatedOn() ? 1 : -1;
});

$balance = 0;

foreach ($history as $row) {
    if ($row->getSender() === $user) {
        $balance -= $row->getTokens();
    }

    if ($row->getRecipient() === $user) {
        $balance += $row->getTokens();
    }
}

return $balance;
```

Structure of table:

**transaction**

- id
- sender_id
- recipient_id
- contract_id
- tokens
- price
- created_on

And i would like to have a single int as balance number.

Comment: I added the table structure and what i want as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to translate this into calls to your entitymanager interface, but here's some SQL that should do the job and be fairly easy to read:

```
SELECT credits.total - debits.total AS balance
FROM 
 (SELECT SUM(tokens) AS total 
  FROM `transaction`
  WHERE sender_id = :user
  AND contract_id = :contract) AS debits
CROSS JOIN 
 (SELECT SUM(tokens) AS total
  FROM `transaction`
  WHERE recipient_id = :user 
  AND contract_id = :contract) AS credits
```

You should have these two indexes to optimize this best:

- `(sender_id, contract_id, tokens)`
- `(recipient_id, contract_id, tokens)`

To test, I created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sender_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `recipient_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `contract_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tokens` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sender_id` (`sender_id`,`contract_id`,`tokens`),
  KEY `recipient_id` (`recipient_id`,`contract_id`,`tokens`)
);
```

Here's some sample data. Two debits and three credits, with 3 tokens in each transaction:

```
INSERT INTO `transaction` VALUES 
(1,10,20,1,3,19.95,'2019-01-20 15:41:47'),
(2,10,20,1,3,19.95,'2019-01-20 15:41:47'),
(3,30,10,1,3,19.95,'2019-01-20 15:41:47'),
(4,30,10,1,3,19.95,'2019-01-20 15:41:47'),
(5,20,10,1,3,19.95,'2019-01-20 15:41:47');
```

Here's the query EXPLAIN report, showing use of covering indexes in each subquery:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>  | system | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL        |    1 | NULL        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3>  | system | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL        |    1 | NULL        |
|  3 | DERIVED     | transaction | ref    | recipient_id  | recipient_id | 8       | const,const |    3 | Using index |
|  2 | DERIVED     | transaction | ref    | sender_id     | sender_id    | 8       | const,const |    2 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
```

Output of the query for user id=`10` and contract_id=`1`:

```
+---------+
| balance |
+---------+
|       3 |
+---------+
```